# when restart CountDownTimer, it finish work

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I want to stop CountDownTimer and to restart it, with time when it stopped. I have this code in class CountDownTimer

```
public class MyDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

long mills;
public MyDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    this.mills=millisInFuture;
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {

    GameScreen.showWindow("Time is over","Sorry, time is Over, you lose");
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    mills=millisUntilFinished/1000;
    GameManager.time= millisUntilFinished/1000;
}       
}
```

and Dialog class, he must to showing, when user click in button 'pause'.
Dialog code, as you can see, i start new CountDownTimer in this code

```
 public static void showWindowPause(final MyDownTimer dTime){

    final Dialog wdialog= new Dialog(context);
    wdialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_window);
    wdialog.setTitle("title");
    TextView text=(TextView)wdialog.findViewById(R.id.txtFirstWord);
    text.setText("mainText");
    Button dialogButton=(Button)wdialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            wdialog.dismiss();              
            dTime.start();


        }
    });
    wdialog.show();

}
```

and method, where I stoping CountDownTimer and show Dialog window.

```
long stime =dTime.mills;
dTime.cancel();
dTime=null;
dTime= new MyDownTimer(stime,1000);
GameScreen.showWindowPause(dTime);
```

when i click button in Dialog window, i see new Dialog, which created in method

```
MyDownTimer.onFinish()
```

But if I change line

```
long stime =dTime.mills;
```

on

```
long stime =5000;
```

CountDownTimer restarts,and all normal.
where i made mistake?

Comment: I want to make pause in Timer and show Dialog. I make breakpoint like this `long stime =dTime.mills;` and create new MyDownTimer, and when close window Dialog, show new dialog window which created in `onFinish()`.if I made `long stime =5000;` - all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really confusing , but I THINK I found something that doesn't make sense.

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mills=millisUntilFinished/1000;     
    GameManager.time= millisUntilFinished/1000;
}
```

I think it should be

```
mills=millisUntilFinished - 1000;
```

edit: If you are actually converting millseconds to seconds, then you'll need to do

```
long stime =dTime.mills*1000;
```

Comment: No, i converting from millisecond to second. and make this - `millisUntilFinished/1000.`

Comment: edited my answer, if you are actually using the dTime.mills somewhere I can't see, then you need to multiply dTime.mills by 1000 when you assign it to "stime"